# Location updates get slow at once per 10 minutes when using WorkManager

Tags: android

I use WorkManager to start a Worker and start to fetch location update from the Worker.
What I notice is the location update becomes very slow, in a frequency of once per 10 minutes, when the phone is locked, compared to once per 1 second when the phone is unlocked.

Here are my questions

1. Is it common that location update becomes slow when an App / task runs in background?
2. Do we have to use Foreground Service in this case?
3. Any other choice?

Comment: This is Doze mode.  I'm surprised you're getting 10 minutes, it should be closer to 15.  It's a battery saving feature of Android that reduces the amount of time allowed for processing when the phone is idle.  Your only way around it is to get the user to whitelist you from power management.  You can't do it yourself, the setting has to be manually set by the user.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: The phone is not in Doze mode. It is immediately slow after I lock the phone, stationary or on my driving. Doze needs stationary for a period of time.

Comment: Incorrect, Doze mode does not need to be stationary.  What you're describing is a perfect match to Doze.  Most likely your device is set to enter Doze more aggressively.

Comment: This is from the document you mentioned. "If a user leaves a device unplugged and stationary for a period of time, with the screen off, the device enters Doze mode. " . and "As soon as the user wakes the device by moving it, turning on the screen, or connecting a charger, the system exits Doze and all apps return to normal activity." To keep moving, I bring the phone with me, shaking it and even driving. What I notice is the location update slow down like this immediately after I make the screen off.

Comment: The documentation isn't always 100% correct.  OEMs tweak things.  What you're describing is exactly how Doze mode works and what it looks like.